# Book about girl who moved away from home with family to US frontier

Tags: identification-request

Around 2005~2008 I read a book about a young girl who left her home when her parents moved to another house. If I'm not mistaken, they moved to Western US during Manifest Destiny-California Gold Rush. She complained how she liked her old home, where her grandma cooked pies which smelled real nice, while her new city she lived in tents and there was mud everywhere.

Then, after years go by, she goes back to her old house, just to find it abandoned after everyone moved out after so long. Then she realizes that "home" is where everyone she has relationships are, and there's no point moving back to her old house since now she will be living all alone by herself. Then she resumes living in the American frontier.